# How to implement a "reply to this email" feature for my web application?

Tags: email, web-applications

I have an application that sends emails when a user creates/modifies a record. I would like my users to be able to reply to the email that was sent to them and have the web application receive the email, parse it and update the record automatically. I have seen this done in web apps like Basecamp. The email usually says "Reply above this line", and if you simply reply to the email, you don't have to log in to the web application in order to update your ticket/conversation.

How can I go about implementing this sort of functionaly? (I'm not looking for a particular language implementation, but rather a language agnostic solution).

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways you can do this:

1. You could use a [Procmail filter](http://www.panix.com/help/mail.procmail.html) to pipe the incoming email to your script. This would need some 'nix knowhow to setup - but it's certainly possible to do what you described via this method.
2. Use a service like [MailGun](http://www.mailgun.com/) - they do all the hard work of setting up and configuring the mail server stuff and expose it to you via a nice programmable web API. I've been evaluating it this week to solve a similar problem like the one you are having and I can tell you: it is really cool and I highly recommend you check it out yourself.

Comment: How exactly do you do this with MailGun? I couldn't find a webhook on email received.

Comment: (comment on previous message) ok found it, you need to use "Route"

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to implement a service/daemon that polls an email inbox for new messages. To relate an incoming email to the corresponding data, you can include an id in the outgoing email's subject.

Comment: by topic do you mean Email subject? so you would recommend I parse the subject line for the id?

Comment: Yes, with someid=[theid], and inform the user not to edit the subject.

Answer (score 0):

I agree you should created a system to receive the incoming email but I don't necessarily agree that polling for it is the correct solution. Take a look at a blog post I wrote on the subject [here](http://steve.dynedge.co.uk/2010/09/07/incoming-email-in-rails-3-choosing-the-right-approach/). It relates to Rails but the concepts should work in any language. That's why we wrote the CloudMailin system to provide a better way of receiving the email.

Also you can use a unique from address for each email that would prevent the user from altering the subject line being a problem. The disposable part of an email address is useful for that. reply+user123@example.com for example.

Comment: I would have liked to use plus/minus addressing like you mentioned, but unfortunately that feature is not supported on the mail server we are using (Microsoft Exchange).

Comment: I always assumed the + thing was Gmail specific but cool to know it isn't. although we send emails via Amazon Marketplace so they need to be registered accounts